# Get Entry from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing classic asp.net website and struggling with a problem.

Usually in URL send data by doing this: localhost/MyrandomPage.aspx?UserName=RandomUsername

But i am trying to make a page more personal so i want Url to look like this:

localhost.com/Profile/RandomUsername

And i am cant find a way how to retrive RandomUserName after slash in Url.

ive done Routing:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("",
            "/Pages/{UserName}",
            "~/Pages/Profile.aspx");
    }
```

But how do i retrive UserName??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get it using
`Page.RouteData.Values["UserName"] as string`

Scott Gu has a [good blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) covering routing in webforms.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your routing scheme is correct and everything works, you can get the route values (in this case the 'action') from the request context:

```
string userName = (string) requestContext.RouteData.Values["UserName"];
```